# Substract value with a loop in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm stuck with something I could do in other languages so I hope someone could help me
I have two tables, one is with my budget number and the remaining budget on each command
Another table with my worker actuals
Here an example of what I'm trying to do:

Table A

```
Command Number         Remainig Work
PO1111                      3
PO1112                     10
```

Table B

```
Command Number:             Actuals:       Name     Date
PO1111                         1            A       11/06
PO1111                         1            A       11/07
PO1111                         1            B       11/06
PO1111                         1            B       11/07
PO1111                         1            B       11/08
PO1111                         1            B       11/10
PO1111                         1            B       11/11
PO1112                         1            A       11/09
PO1112                         1            A       11/10
```

So Finally I'd Like something like:

```
Date    Worker     Actuals
11/06    A            1
11/07    A            1
11/06    B            1
11/07    B          Error
11/08    B          Error
11/10    B          Error
11/11    B          Error
11/09    A            1
11/10    A            1
```

Command Number

Remainig budget: 32h

Worker A worked 40h and Worker B 16h
So I'd like to get my result like that:
For worker A:

```
Day:      Hours:
1           8
2           8
3           8
4           8 
5         ERROR
```

For worker B:

```
Day       Hours
1         ERROR
2         ERROR
```

So I think I should do something with a while but I don't know how to substract the previous value with my actual
SO if someone could help me

Thanks for your help

Comment: why do u need ERROR line? which DBMS?

Comment: You don't want to loop. You are working with record sets, not arrays or lists or collections or dictionaries. Please share some sample data (what it looks like in your tables) and your desired results and we can help. Probably a cumulative sum (window function) is right here. Also very important, share which RDBMS you are using (mysql, sql server, postgres, oracle, etc)

Comment: How do you decide which workers comes first? Can you share the table schema?

Comment: what does your table look like?

Comment: Because I'll use this data for a report
So I tought to use something like IF Value>0(Value, 'ERROR')
I'm working on Sql Server
I'm gonna edit my post o give you more details

Comment: @freedumz . . . I don't get it.  Why does B get the error and not A?

Comment: I take my worker by alphabetic order

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think that it's because it goes over budget. He needs a CTE with a row number and then use a theta join to calculate the cumulative hours.

Comment: @NicVerAZ Yes you are right
Once it goes over budget, I have an error message

Comment: @freedumz So you need to learn about Common Table Expression. We do not loop in SQL, except in some rare one-time transformation scripts where you want to unit test each step individually. It's not production worthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function `sum` partitioned by `CommandNumber` using `rows unbounded preceding`

```
declare @A Table (CommandNumber varchar(100), RemainigWork integer)
declare @B Table (CommandNumber varchar(100), Actuals integer, Name varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @A(CommandNumber, RemainigWork) values('PO1111', 3)
INSERT INTO @b(CommandNumber, Actuals, Name) values('PO1111', 1, 'A')
INSERT INTO @b(CommandNumber, Actuals, Name) values('PO1111', 1, 'A')
INSERT INTO @b(CommandNumber, Actuals, Name) values('PO1111', 1, 'B')
INSERT INTO @b(CommandNumber, Actuals, Name) values('PO1111', 1, 'B')
INSERT INTO @b(CommandNumber, Actuals, Name) values('PO1111', 1, 'B')

select
    a.CommandNumber,
    case when sum(Actuals) over (partition by a.CommandNumber order by b.name rows unbounded preceding) > RemainigWork 
        then 
            'Error' 
        else 
            CAST(Actuals as varchar(100)) 
        end as Actuals,
    b.Name
from @A a
join @B b on a.CommandNumber = b.CommandNumber
```

Comment: Thank a lot
I didn't know windows function :)